# Counting rows when generating XML data

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm generating a XML. I have a requirement to create some kind of sequence. Something like rownum or row_number().

```
   select XMLROOT ( xmlagg(
                       xmlelement(
                         "table_description", 
                          xmlelement(
                            "table_name",
                            max(table_name)
                          ),
                          xmlelement(
                            "table_sequence"
                          ),
                          xmlelement(
                            "table_columns",
                            xmlagg(
                              xmlforest(
                              column_name as "column_name",
                              '' as "column_sequence"
                              )
                            )
                          )
                      )
                ), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES) 
    from all_tab_columns 
    where owner='SYS' 
    and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
    group by table_name;
```

So for example in this query I would like to add one sequence for each table_name element that will increment by one , and one sequence for each iteration of column_name that will increment by one BUT will be reset on the next grouping.

Pseudo code

```
<table_description>
  <table_sequence>1</table_sequence>
  <table_name>xyz</table_name>
  <table_columns>
    <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    <column_name>Column One</column_name>
    <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
    <column_name>Column two</column_name>
  </table_columns>
<table_description>
  <table_sequence>2</table_sequence>
  <table_name>abs</table_name>
  <table_columns>
    <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    <column_name>Column One</column_name>
    <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
    <column_name>Column two</column_name>
  </table_columns>
<table_description>
```

Comment: Your output doesn't look right; should the column sequence be a node under the column? Or perhaps more clearly, should the sequence values be attributes of the table and column nodes? Also which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm sorry I guess I wasn't clear enough. I'm perfectly aware the output is not the same as what the input from above would give. I just wanted to give a pseudo example of what the output should look like. I'll format it more properly with what I really want to get. I'm using oracle 10XE.

Comment: Sequence should be sibling with its appropriate nodes. column_name and column_sequence should be siblings. Same with table_name and table_Sequence.

Comment: I've edited both input code and pseudo code so I think it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `from all_tab_columns` to an inline view which generates the sequence numbers via `dense_rank()`:

```
from (
  select atc.*,
    dense_rank() over (order by table_name) as table_sequence,
    dense_rank() over (partition by table_name order by column_name) as column_sequence
  from all_tab_columns atc
  where owner='SYS' 
  and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
)
```

And you can then use those generated columns in your XML:

```
select XMLROOT ( xmlagg(
                   xmlelement(
                     "table_description", 
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_name",
                        table_name
                      ),
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_sequence",
                        table_sequence
                      ),
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_columns",
                        xmlagg(
                          xmlforest(
                          column_name as "column_name",
                          column_sequence as "column_sequence"
                          )
                        )
                      )
                  )
            ), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES) 
from (
  select atc.*,
    dense_rank() over (order by table_name) as table_sequence,
    dense_rank() over (partition by table_name order by column_name) as column_sequence
  from all_tab_columns atc
  where owner='SYS' 
  and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
)
where owner='SYS' 
and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
group by table_name, table_sequence;
```

which gets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE</table_name>
  <table_sequence>1</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_name>DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME</column_name>
    <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    <column_name>RULE_OWNER</column_name>
    <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    <column_name>RULE_NAME</column_name>
    <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE</table_name>
  <table_sequence>2</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_name>EXECUTE_EVENT</column_name>
    <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    <column_name>RULE_OWNER</column_name>
    <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    <column_name>RULE_NAME</column_name>
    <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS</table_name>
  <table_sequence>3</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_name>APPLY_DATABASE_LINK</column_name>
    <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    <column_name>OBJECT_OWNER</column_name>
    <column_sequence>4</column_sequence>
    <column_name>OBJECT_NAME</column_name>
    <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    <column_name>COLUMN_NAME</column_name>
    <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
```

Your generated XML is still not right though, as there is no link between each column and its sequence number. Maybe you want something more like:

```
select XMLROOT ( xmlagg(
                   xmlelement(
                     "table_description", 
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_name",
                        table_name
                      ),
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_sequence",
                        table_sequence
                      ),
                      xmlelement(
                        "table_columns",
                        xmlagg(
                          xmlelement(
                            "column_description", 
                            xmlforest(
                              column_name as "column_name",
                              column_sequence as "column_sequence"
                            )
                          )
                        )
                      )
                  )
            ), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES) 
from (
  select atc.*,
    dense_rank() over (order by table_name) as table_sequence,
    dense_rank() over (partition by table_name order by column_name) as column_sequence
  from all_tab_columns atc
  where owner='SYS' 
  and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
)
where owner='SYS' 
and table_name in ('ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE','ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE','ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS') 
group by table_name, table_sequence;
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_ENQUEUE</table_name>
  <table_sequence>1</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME</column_name>
      <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>RULE_OWNER</column_name>
      <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>RULE_NAME</column_name>
      <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_EXECUTE</table_name>
  <table_sequence>2</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>EXECUTE_EVENT</column_name>
      <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>RULE_OWNER</column_name>
      <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>RULE_NAME</column_name>
      <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
<table_description>
  <table_name>ALL_APPLY_KEY_COLUMNS</table_name>
  <table_sequence>3</table_sequence>
  <table_columns>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>APPLY_DATABASE_LINK</column_name>
      <column_sequence>1</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>OBJECT_OWNER</column_name>
      <column_sequence>4</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>OBJECT_NAME</column_name>
      <column_sequence>3</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
    <column_description>
      <column_name>COLUMN_NAME</column_name>
      <column_sequence>2</column_sequence>
    </column_description>
  </table_columns>
</table_description>
```

Comment: Currently it doesn't matter if columns are in parent node ,as this is just an example ,but it is a valid concern. Thanks for the help!